# django hyperlink no middlepart

Tags: python, django, templates, url, hyperlink

i got a problem with a hyperlink in my django template.

The link:

```
<a href="/users/character/{{ character.name }}/">Profile</a>
```

And this somehow gois to "/character/{{ character.name }}/"

When i typ the link manualy the view and the template work

My full template(all works except the link i quoted before):

```
{% if characters|length > 0 %}
    {% for character in characters %}
        <p><a href="/characters/{{ character.id }}/"><img>{{character.open}}(WN)</img></a></p>
        <ul><a href="/characters/{{ character.id }}/">{{character.name}}(WN)</a></ul>
        <ul>{{character.faction}}</ul>

        {% if character.protected %}
            <ul><font color="green"><b>PROTECTED</b></font></ul>
        {% endif %}

     <ul><a href="/users/character/{{ character.name }}/">Profile</a></ul>
{% endfor %}

{% endif %} 
{% if characters|length < 3 %}

    <p><a href="/users/{{ user.id }}/create/">New Character(WN)</a></p>


{% endif %}
```

and my urls:

```
#site.urls
url(r'^users/', include('users.urls')),
url(r'^users/', include ('characters.urls')),

#characters.urls
url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/characters/$', views.user_characters, name='user_characters'),
url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/create/$', views.create_character, name='create_character'),
url(r'^character/(?P<character_name>[^/]+)/$', views.character_profile, name='character_profile'),
```

can anyone please help me out on this,
Got no clue where i could be going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: If you wnat to see other parts of my code, please tell me

Comment: Show the view wich renders this template?

Comment: MY excuses, i figured it out. Somehow 2 links got swapped around a was b and b was a.  Fixed it and now it works.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for url you should use [naming url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) in your template it will looks like:

```
{% url 'character_profile' character.name %}
```

Comment: hm ok im going to try that